# Using rtx 2070 super in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, virtualbox

I'm using ubuntu on a vm and was wondering if I am capable of utilizing my gpu to improve performance on simulations. I have done some extensive research onto the subject but nothing has helped me. First thing I tried was to check if I was able to download the nvidia drivers through the software and updates app but the only thing it detected was VMware: SVGA II Adapter and InnoTek Systemberatung GmbH: VirtualBox Guest Service; both say that this device is not working and the only thing I could select on either of them is the " continue using a manually installed driver" tab. Next I tried to see if it was detected through the terminal by following the steps here: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ubuntu-linux-install-nvidia-driver-latest-proprietary-driver/#verification . Once I reached the verification step I recieved this message: " NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldnt communicate with the nvidia driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running" " I installed version 440 since it was the latest driver I found after the apt nvidia driver search. I also followed the steps for using the ppa repository  from this link: https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-the-nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux after purging the previously intsalled drivers. I got to the second step " sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall" and recieved the message "some packages could not be installed... The following packages have unmet dependencies: virutualbox-guest-dkms-hwe : conflicts: virtualbox-giest-dkms
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages." I would appreciate any help here, and if this is not possible I will be very sad but will get over it so please tell me asap.

pc specs if needed:
nvidia rtx 2070 super
ubuntu 18.04
ryzen 3700x

Comment: I haven't played around with it, but I recall that VirtualBox requires an extension to enable GPU "passthrough" and you can read about it [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/virtualization/virtualbox/6.0/admin/pcipassthrough.html). However, I can't tell if you're using VirtualBox or VMWare and I've never needed to try the passthrough extension.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I will look into it! I am using virtual box.